# Discord music bot saying I need to send a second argument even when i do

Tags: discord.js

Whats wrong with my code, I cant seem to figure it out. Followed a few tutorials before and made a few simple bots on my own, but cant seem to figure this out. Its not playing music nor connecting to the vc
Heres My Code:

const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
name: 'play',
description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
async execute(message, args) {
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

```
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!'); 
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');

    const validURL = (str) =>{
        var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
        if(!regex.test(str)){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if(validURL(args[0])){

        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});

        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
        .on('finish', () =>{
            voiceChannel.leave();
            message.channel.send('leaving channel');
        });

        await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)

        return
    }

    
    const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();

    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

        return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

    }

    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

    if(video){
        const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
        .on('finish', () =>{
            voiceChannel.leave();
        });

        await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
    } else {
        message.channel.send('No video results found');
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main principle we want to focus on here is **Guard Statements** which you make good use of in your code.

If you aren't already familiar, a guard statement is one that resides at the top of a block of code and prevents the execution of code below it if a specific condition is met. This is really useful for making discord bots because it will allow us to stop command execution if the permission to use it is missing for example (which you use in your code provided)

The caveat here is that in your specific guard statement where you check for the number of args used, you provide this line:

```
if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
```

Now, there's nothing wrong with this line, except that we're only checking if the property **length** doesn't exist on **args** which isn't what we're really trying to check.

If we want to make sure that there are **exactly** two arguments provided, we would want to rewrite the condition like this:

```
if (args.length == 2) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
```

From here, you can change the condition to meet your desired requirements and it should work great!

Comment: Thank you, so much that helped me out a lot, but now I'm running into another issue which is it not detecting when I'm in the voice channel or not which then leads to You need to be in a channel to execute this command issue. It seems like I would do it with another Guard Statement, but don't know how I would check it/ what value I assign to it. The discord.js documentation was no help.

Comment: Could you expand your code in your post to show the entire file or the entire method? I can't see how you're defining "voiceChannel" and I need to see that to help

Comment: I just realized, I never define voice channel, dont really know why its in there, this code is from a couple of months ago and I just decided I wanted to work on it again.

Comment: All good. If you define voice channel, just use the properties on the object to check if the user that executed the command is in the user list for the channel